# Is there a way to gauge how clogged the EOS resource exchange is where transactions would get stuck?

Tags: cpu, resources, bandwidth, network

With the recent resources causing transactions to get stuck. Is there a way to gauge if my transaction would get stuck? Is there some type of graph or chart to see how much of the resources are free to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command line argument:

`cleos -u $eos get table eosio eosio rexpool`

This will show a result something like this:

```
{
  "rows": [{
      "version": 0,
      "total_lent": "47137407.6385 EOS",
      "total_unlent": "20952015.1375 EOS",
      "total_rent": "11766.0122 EOS",
      "total_lendable": "68089422.7760 EOS",
      "total_rex": "677469852402.5966 REX",
      "namebid_proceeds": "0.0000 EOS",
      "loan_num": 256463
    }
  ],
  "more": false,
  "next_key": ""
}
```

Here you can see how much EOS is being lent, and how much is still lendable, etc.

There are also various websites which show REX statistics, such as https://bloks.io/rex?tab=pool

Comment: Is there a website I can just goto that tells me if its clogged or not.

Comment: I added a website to my answer